# Authorisation error with Google API php client

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api

I try to use Google API PHP client to make my application use its Google Drive account in offline way, because I dont want my application to redirect every time to google for getting authorisation.

So when I connect for the first time and recieve credentials with access_token and refresh_token I backup it and try to use it every time.

Problem is that it works till expiration and than , when API client tries to refresh acces token I'm keep getting this error:

Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_request", "error_description" : "Client must specify either client_id or client_assertion, not both" }

My stored credentials are in json form:

{"access_token":"XXX","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"refresh_token":"XXX,"created":1406537500}

My code (taken from Google tutorials with some changes):

```
function exchangeCode($authorizationCode) {
    try {
        $client = new Google_Client();

        $client->setClientId(self::$clientId);
        $client->setClientSecret(self::$clientSacred);
        $client->setRedirectUri(self::getRedirectURI());
        $_GET['code'] = $authorizationCode;
        return $client->authenticate();
    } catch (Google_AuthException $e) {
        echo 'An Google_AuthException occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
        throw new CodeExchangeException(null);
    }
}

function getCredentials($authorizationCode, $state='') {
    $emailAddress = '';
    try {
        $credentials = self::exchangeCode($authorizationCode);

        $credentialsArray = json_decode($credentials, true);
         if (isset($credentialsArray['refresh_token'])) {
             self::storeCredentials($credentials);
             return $credentials;
         } else {
            $credentials = self::getStoredCredentials();
             $credentialsArray = json_decode($credentials, true);
             if ($credentials != null &&
                     isset($credentialsArray['refresh_token'])) {
                    return $credentials;
            }
        }
    } catch (CodeExchangeException $e) {
        print 'An CodeExchangeException occurred during code exchange.';
        $e->setAuthorizationUrl(self::getAuthorizationUrl($emailAddress, $state));
        throw $e;
    } catch (NoUserIdException $e) {
        print 'No e-mail address could be retrieved.';
    }

    $authorizationUrl = self::getAuthorizationUrl($emailAddress, $state);
    throw new NoRefreshTokenException($authorizationUrl);
}

function buildService($credentials) {
    $apiClient = new Google_Client();
     $apiClient->setUseObjects(true);
    $apiClient->setAccessToken($credentials);

    return new Google_DriveService($apiClient);
}


function test()
{
    $credentials = self::getStoredCredentials();
    if ( empty($credentials) )
    {
        if (!isset($_GET["code"]))
        {
            header("location:".self::getAuthorizationUrl("xxx@gmail.com", ''));
            die();
        }
        $credentials = self::getCredentials($_GET["code"]);
        echo "NEW: ".$credentials;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "STORED: ".$credentials;
    }

    $service = self::buildService($credentials);




}
```

The error happends in buildService method when its client object tries to refresh based on credentials passed.

Comment: I probably solved it my self. It works for now. So as You can see in my code in buildService function I set only fields that are needed when my credentials are up to date. But when they expire, in order to make valid refresh client object has to be filled with rest of needed field. Fields that I added are clientId, Scopes, Access type and client sacred.